# Using groovy-wslite in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI version 4.5.1 on a Windows 7 box to create a mock webservice. It includes a Groovy script that is fired at an OnRequest event which attempts to create and send a second response.

The issue is to do with the installation of the groovy-wslite library, which I'm trying to use in order to instantiate a SoapClient object which sends the additional response.

If I include the following at the top of the script (as per the wslite github site at https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite):

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.7.1')
```

... I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/IvySettings
```

If I remove it from the script, I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script6.groovy: 23: unable to resolve class SOAPClient @ line 23, column 18.
       def client = new SOAPClient(clientURL)
                    ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class SOAPClient  @ line 23, column 18.
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, please? Do I need to install groovy-wslite separately within SoapUI?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the groovy-wslite jar and added it to my SoapUI installation's bin/ext directory.